# Why does this GC overhead limit exceed occur?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, out-of-memory

I am reading and parsing a file of plain text, reading line by line, breaking each line into sentences, splitting each sentence into words and store them into List per sentence and per doc.

The input file contains 5 million lines, so I set the ArrayList's size to be 5005000. My heap size in IntelliJ is below:

```
# custom IntelliJ IDEA VM options

-Xms128m
-Xmx8192m
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=240m
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
-XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=50
-ea
-Dsun.io.useCanonCaches=false
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
-XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow
```

My laptop has 15G RAM. After it reads 4500000 lines (as shown by print statement), it then becomes very slow. After several minutes, I received:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
```

Each line (parsed as one document) is short, so my 15G memory should be more than enough to hold it. The text file size is only 800MB. While I am watching my performance monitor in Windows 10, it shows only about 55% memory is used, which says there is still lots of memory available when it dies.

One note, in the code below, I use 'sentence.toCharArray()', because it isn't English, so I basically treats each character as a word in my implementation.

Only 5 million lines, and why is it dead?

```
        List<List<List<String>>> allWords = new ArrayList<>(5005000);
        System.out.println("Load text from file: ");
        try {
            BufferedReader br = Utils.fileReader(filePath);

            String line;
            int lineNo = 0;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                List<List<String>> wordsPerDoc = new ArrayList<>();
                for (String sentence : segment(line)) {
                    List<String> wordsPerSentence = new ArrayList<>();
                    for (Character c : sentence.toCharArray()) {
                        wordsPerClause.add(Character.toString(c));
                    }
                    wordsPerDoc.add(wordsPerSentence);
                }
                allWords.add(wordsPerDoc);
                lineNo++;
                if(lineNo % 500000 ==0) {
                    System.out.println(lineNo);
                }
            }
            System.out.println("Loaded text from file. ");

            br.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (br != null) {
                try {
                    br.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

public List<String> segment(final String line) {
        List<String> sentences = new ArrayList<>();
        StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(line, OtherConstants.BASIC_TOKENIZATION_DELIMITER, true);
        while (tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
            String word = tokenizer.nextToken();
                sentences.add(word);
        }
        return sentences;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're changing the memory profile *for* IntelliJ.

To change it for your app instead: go to the run menu in the top-right; find your main class; click on "Edit Configurations"; and set "VM options" to `-Xmx4g` for a 4 GB heap for your app.

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/run-debug-configuration-application.html for docs